# How to set compression level with `png_image_write_to_file `?

Tags: c++, png, libpng

I use this to write image to file with the help of libpng:

```
    png_image image;
    memset(&image, 0, (sizeof image));
    image.version = PNG_IMAGE_VERSION;
    image.format = PNG_FORMAT_RGBA;
    image.width = width;
    image.height = height;
    png_image_write_to_file(&image, path.c_str(), 0/*convert_to_8bit*/,buffer.data(), 0/*row_stride*/, NULL/*colormap*/);
```

I know api `png_set_compression_level` could be used. However, where should I put it? I cant get the `png_structrp`.

Comment: I wasn't aware that PNG had compression levels, because it's lossless compression. There's no reason not to use the maximum compression from the start.

Comment: @MarkRansom Refer to [this](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.0/LSB-Desktop-generic/LSB-Desktop-generic/libpng12.png.set.compression.level.1.html), `compression levels 3-6 usually perform as well as level 9 for PNG images, and do considerably fewer caclulations`.

Comment: So evidently you need to look at the documentation for `zlib` too.